# Who is the author of the science fiction novel, "Gem?" or is it "Jem?"

Tags: story-identification, novel

I think the title comes from "Geminorum," the star which the planet the action takes place on orbits. In the universe of the novel, the Earth is divided between three political blocs, the Western, sort of a USA led deal, the People's block, who's major resource is just having lots of people, and a third, I've forgotten. Each bloc has a representative group of explorers and each group allies themselves with a different indigenous intelligent species. When the political blocs go to war on Earth, the explorers go to war on Gem. They lose touch with Earth and have to make peace in the end and the politics are forgotten as they  need to come together to survive. In the end there are humans and the three other species, all living in an integrated society.

The novel was written in the 70s or early 80s I'm pretty sure, as it was based on cold war politics. I bought this book in paperback in like 1982 when I was a kid. I'd love to read it again.

Comment: Are you certain that the title of the novel is "Gem?" If that is the correct title, the book should be very easy to find, but nothing relevant is coming up for me with that title on Google. If that isn't the correct title of the book, or you're not sure if it is or it isn't, then the title of this question is a bit misleading, and should probably be altered.

Answer (score 5):

You:re looking for [*Jem*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1688) (1979) by Frederik Pohl.

The blurb from Google books reads:

> The discovery of another habitable world might spell salvation to the three bitterly competing power blocs of the resource-starved 21st century; but when their representatives arrive on Jem, with its multiple intelligent species, they discover instead the perfect situation into which to export their rivalries. Subtitled, with savage irony, 'The Making of a Utopia', JEM is one of Frederik Pohl's most powerful novels.

(The three Earth blocs don't directly correspond to any contemporary nations, but are defined by a resource they monopolize: water, oil and people.)